# Mapping associated entity's columns to associating entity fields

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

There is a read-only 'Catalog' entity which has preconfigured data in the table. 'BookCatalog' is another entity which has many-to-one relationships with 'Catalog' table.

Currently my config files are as follows,

```
<!--Catalog -->
<class name="xxxx.Catalog" table="CATALOG" mutable="false">
   ....
   ....
   <property name="a" type="string">
      <column name="A" />
   </property>
   <property name="b" type="string">
      <column name="B" />
   </property>
</class>

<!-- Book Catalog -->
<class name="xxxx.BookCatalog" table="BOOK_CATALOG">
    ....
    ....
    <many-to-one name="base_catalog" class="xxxx.Catalog" fetch="select">
        <column name="BASE_CATALOG_ID" length="36" />
    </many-to-one>

    <property name="c" type="string">
      <column name="C" />
   </property>
</class>
```

Currently if I want to access read-only properties a & b, I need to access through 'base_catalog' field.

I prefer to make BookCatalog as a sub-class of Catalog and map properties a & b from the 'CATALOG' read-only table.

I know I can use 'formula' for each and every fields in CATALOG table but since i have many more fields, it is not efficient.

Is there any other way in hibernate to map associated entity's columns to associating entity fields?

or

Is there any better database design to solve this issue?

Comment: What "issue" do you want to solve?

Comment: I don't understand why you derive it. When the properties of the Catalog are read-only, it is certainly not a good idea to derive it and make the derived entity properties mutable (which also means that it can be created and removed). Did you notice that you can't create new BookCatalogs when it derives from Catalog which is pre-configured. May be you don't need to... But then you can just use normal inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `<component>` as below :

```
<class name="xxxx.BookCatalog" table="BOOK_CATALOG" mutable="false">
  <property name="c" type="string">
    <column name="C" />
  </property>
  <component name = "xxxx.Catalog">
    <property name="a" type="string">
      <column name="A" />
    </property>
    <property name="b" type="string">
      <column name="B" />
    </property>
 </component>
</class>
```